# doubling a string using a submethod

Tags: arrays, string, list

How do you write a static method called `doubleList` that takes an `ArrayList` of `Strings` as a formal parameter and replaces every String with two of that same String?

For example, if the list stores the values `["how", "are", "you"]` before the method is called, it should store the values `["how", "how", "are", "are", "you", "you"]` after the method finishes executing.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
   ArrayList<String> x = new ArrayList<>();  
    x.add("how");
    x.add("are");
    x.add("you");
    System.out.println(x);
    doubleList(x);
    System.out.println(x);


    public static void doubleList(ArrayList<String> list, String t) 
{

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class MyReplicatingClass {

    private static ArrayList<String> arrayList;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        arrayList.add("how");
        arrayList.add("are");
        arrayList.add("you");

        System.out.println(arrayList);
        doubleList(arrayList);
        System.out.println(arrayList);
    }

    private static void doubleList(ArrayList<String> list) {
        ArrayList<String> tmpList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String element : list) {
            int numOfRepeats = 2; // can be changed to 3 -> [how, how, how, ...]
            while (numOfRepeats > 0) {
                tmpList.add(element);
                numOfRepeats--;
            }
        }

        arrayList = new ArrayList<>(tmpList);
    }
}
```

As stated above, it can be customized. Here's the output for a repeat of 6:

```
[how, are, you]
[how, how, how, how, how, how, are, are, are, are, are, are, you, you, you, you, you, you]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void doubleList(ArrayList<String> arrayList){
    for(int i = 0 ; i < arrayList.size() ; i++){
        arrayList.add(i+1, arrayList.get(i));
        i++;
    };
}
```

input ["how", "are", "you?"]

output [how, how, are, are, you?, you?]

Comment: Hi @mustafa welcome to stackoverflow. You should go over the [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) in order to make your answer explain the problem at hand and help future readers as well